# vowel counter and display the letter

Tags: java

```
public class vowel {

    public static void main(String args[]) 
    {
        String sentence;
        int vowels = 0, digits = 0, blanks = 0, consonants=0;
        char ch;
        System.out.print("Enter a String : ");
        sentence = TextIO.getln();
        sentence = sentence.toLowerCase();
        for(int i = 0; i < sentence.length(); i ++)
        {
            ch = sentence.charAt(i);

            if(ch == 'a' || ch == 'e' || ch == 'i' || ch == 'o' || ch == 'u')
                vowels ++;

            else if(ch =='b'|| ch == 'c' || ch == 'd'|| ch =='f' || ch =='g' ||
                    ch == 'h' || ch =='j' || ch =='k'|| ch =='l' || ch =='m' ||
                    ch == 'n' || ch =='p' || ch =='q'|| ch =='r' || ch =='s' ||
                    ch == 't' || ch =='v' || ch =='w'|| ch =='x' || ch =='z' ||
                    ch == 'y')

                consonants ++;
            else if(Character.isDigit(ch))
                digits ++;
            else if(Character.isWhitespace(ch))
                blanks ++;
        }

        System.out.println("Vowels : " + vowels);
        System.out.println("Consonants : " +consonants);
        System.out.println("Digits : " + digits);
        System.out.println("Blanks : " + blanks);
    }
}
```

This program works perfectly in counting, but I wish to add on a function display the word it count

For example, input `ABBCC12`:

```
Vowels :1
Input Vowels : A
Consonants :4
Input Consonants : BBCC
Digits :2
Input Digits :12
```

Can I know what to do next?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks as though the easiest way that would fit with your current way of working would be to keep hold of a `StringBuilder` for each type:

```
vowelsStringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
```

and then whenever you encounter one, you add it on:

```
vowelsStringBuilder.append(ch);
```

At the end, you can then use

```
String vowelsString = vowelsStringBuilder.toString();
```

to get the final `String` containing all the vowels.

In fact, if you do it like this, you don't really need to count them as you go, because you can get the number of vowels at the end with `vowelsString.length()`.